# Visual Studio gives me error if I save when code is not on screen

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 gives me a weird error message for this code.
The thing is the code compiles, builds and runs just fine.

The error I get is this:

[image]

But... If I save while "public:" is on the screen then it removes the error.
[image]

If I save while "public:" is not on screen then the error comes back.

If I go all the way down to my main function and then save, then I get a second error:
[image]

Is this just a bug in Visual Studio 2019? I'm following a tutorial and I'm new to C++ (Java background). Do you need more information?

Why is this error message here, and how can I fix it?

**Complete code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Log
{
public:
    const int LogLevelError = 0;
    const int LogLevelWarning = 1;
    const int LogLevelInfo = 2;

private:
    int m_LogLevel = LogLevelInfo;

public:
    void SetLevel(int level)
    {
        m_LogLevel = level;
    }

    void Error(const char* message)
    {
        if (m_LogLevel >= LogLevelError)
        {
            cout << "[ERROR]:" << message << endl;
        }
    }

    void Info(const char* message)
    {
        if (m_LogLevel >= LogLevelInfo)
        {
            cout << "[INFO]:" << message << endl;
        }
    }

    void Warn(const char* message)
    {
        if (m_LogLevel >= LogLevelWarning)
        {
            cout << "[WARNING]:" << message << endl;
        }
    }
};



int main()
{
    Log log;

    log.SetLevel(log.LogLevelWarning);
    log.Warn("Hello");
    log.Info("Hello");
    log.Error("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio, deleting the intelisense databse file in your solution's directory (`.VC.db` extension in 2017, might have changed in 2019) and try again.

Comment: Folder: .vs/ProjectName/v16/Browse.VC.db   ----    I've deleted it and it was generated back again when I opened the project. But the error still persists.

Comment: Then all I can think of is you might have a non-printable character in a source file, one that doesn't bother the compiler but that trips up intellisense. Try inspecting the files with a hex editor to see if it contains any unexpected bytes.

Comment: VS does that to me on a regular basis, but it never gives me compile errors, so I just ignore it.

Comment: @CruzJean I see. Well... I guess I'll try to ignore it then.